# Pythonic manipulation of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing the following tasks.
Iterating a list of lists.
Converting each of the inner list to a object and adding them to a batch for insert into cassandra. Keeping track the batch doesn't have more than 150 items.

```py
s = session.prepare("INSERT INTO {} (a, b, c) VALUES (?, ?, ?)".format(table))
batch = BatchStatement(consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)
count = 0
for lst in list:
   for i in lst:
      if count == 150:
         magic = Magic(i[0], i[1], content_id)
         batch.add(s, (magic.a, magic.b, magic.c))
         session.execute(batch)
         batch = BatchStatement(consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)
         count = 0
        else:
            for i in lst:
                magic = Magic(i[0], i[1], content_id)
                    batch.add(s, (magic.a, magic.b, magic.c))
                count += 1
    session.execute(batch)
```

The outer list has unspecified number of items but the inner list always has two items.

This code is extremely verbose. Is there a more pythonic way to do this.

Comment: [CodeReview.SE] may be a better place for this question. If you wish to post there, though, review [their standards](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) first.

Comment: Sometimes verbose is good. You can write this with nested list comprehensions but it would be hard to read.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (i.e. that is self contained also w.r.t. to the example data). Also the indentation of the code is wrong. And in case `lst` is really a list, I'm not sure the code in the `else` clause is really doing what you think (since you iterate over the whole list again). Finally you seem to have a list of lists that themselves contain 2-tuples (is this correct?). Some example data would really help to understand this better.

Answer (score 1):

I moved the common code out of the `if` block:

```py
s = session.prepare("INSERT INTO {} (a, b, c) VALUES (?, ?, ?)".format(table))
batch = BatchStatement(consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)
count = 0
for lst in list:
    for i in lst:
        magic = Magic(i[0], i[1], content_id)
        batch.add(s, (magic.a, magic.b, magic.c))
        count += 1
        if count == 150:
            session.execute(batch)
            batch = BatchStatement(consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)
            count = 0
session.execute(batch)
```

I also removed what appears to be an unnecessary second `for` loop. You may want to add a check for `count == 0` before the final call to `session.execute`.

**Warning**

Never use `list` as a variable name. [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) is a built-in class.